# Can't use "super.member.Func()" in javascript. How to rewrite it correctly?

Tags: javascript, class, super

[super in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)
In this I read what can't use super as it:

```
class Base {
  baseField = 10;
}

class Extended extends Base {
  extendedField = super.baseField; // undefined
}
```

My code is:

```
class Parent{
   ext_class;
   constructor(ext){
   this.ext_class=ext;
   }
}

class Child extends Parent{
   constructor(ext){
      super(ext);
   }
   Method(p){
      super.ext_class.ExecFunc(p);
   }


}
```

I can't call function from object in member of parent class. I can save it in child but not sure what it is right.

How do I write it correctly?

```
class Base {
  constructor(bf){
    this.baseField = bf
  }
}

Base.prototype.baseField = 1;

class Extended extends Base {
  constructor(bf){
    super(bf)
  }
  extendedField = super.baseField;
}

console.log(new Extended(12).extendedField);
```

This not work correctly too.

But this work how I need!!!

```
class Base {
  constructor(bf){
    Base.prototype.baseField = bf
  }
}

class Extended extends Base {
  constructor(bf){
    super(bf)
  }
  extendedField = super.baseField;
}
console.log(new Extended(13).extendedField);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should've scrolled further [down](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#accessing_super_in_class_field_declaration):

> Note that instance fields are set on the instance instead of the constructor's prototype, so you can't use super to access the instance field of a superclass.

That means you'd have to put the property on the prototype explicitly like this:

```js
class Base {}

Base.prototype.baseField = 10;

class Extended extends Base {
  extendedField = super.baseField;
}

console.log(new Extended().extendedField);
```

Comment: But I can't use (new Extended(12).extendedFields) and change value in parent with constructor(eF){super(eF)} (sample in ask)

Comment: @DmitryKovalevsky You haven't defined the constructor of `Base` to do that.

Comment: I write sample in end of ask

Comment: @DmitryKovalevsky The constructor runs after `extendedField = super.baseField`, so the value does not change. You would have to use `this.extendedField = super.baseField` after the super call. Also, since `baseField` isn't shadowed by the extended class, you could just use `this.baseField`...

Comment: Thank. I understand! I wrote example in end of ask. It was what I need.